# evoPDF conversion triggering mode not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, evopdf

We are using evoPDF to convert our AngularJS form to PDF. Since the content on the page loads after few service calls, we understood that we need to use the delayed/Manual triggering mode options from evoPDF.

Below is the javascript that needs to be executed after the required delay or the content is loaded completely:

```
    if (typeof evoPdfConverter != "undefined") {
        evoPdfConverter.startConversion();
    }
```

However, when we have the above script on an external JS file and refer the JS file on the main html page, the conversion fails. But when we add this script in the main html page itself(internally), the conversion works.

Is this an issue with evoPDf or any additional scripts to be added? We cannot add any internal scripts on our html page as all the pages are generated dynamically.